# Element wise max comparison of two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes **df1** and **df2**.

```
df1 = 

    A1 B1 C1
0   1  2  0
1   4  2  1
2   2  1  5


df2 =

    A2 B2 C2
0   2  1  5
1   1  3  2
2   2  2  4
```

And I wish to create a third dataframe which has the max values between the corresponding elements of the two dataframes.

I.e.

```
df3 = max(df1, df2)

print(df3)

    A3 B3 C3
0   2  2  5
1   4  3  2
2   2  2  5
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it's worth noting but in my actual case the index is of datetime format.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `DataFrame.max` over the index:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).max(level=0)
df3.columns = df3.columns.str.replace("\d", "3", regex=True)
```

```
   A3  B3  C3
0   2   2   5
1   4   3   2
2   2   2   5
```

Answer (score 1):

try via `where()` method and `rename()` method:

```
out=df1.where(df1.values>df2.values,df2.values).rename(columns=lambda x:x[0]+'3')
```

**OR**

via numpy's `where()` and `DataFrame()` method:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1.values>df2.values,df1.values,df2.values),columns=['A3','B3','C3'])
```

output of `out`:

```
    A3  B3  C3
0   2   2   5
1   4   3   2
2   2   2   5
```